# '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile' prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, installation, prerequisites, .net-client-profile

I have a .Net Setup Project and set the install location for prerequisites to 'download from same location as my application'.

I downloaded the 'Microsoft .NET Framework Client Profile Offline Installer' from https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=992cffcb-f8ce-41d9-8bd6-31f3e216285c and put it in the directories:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35Client
and
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFx35Client

But I still get the error message "prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFx35Client\DotNetFx35ClientSetup.exe' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile' can not be located on disk."

Any idea?

I have windows 7 and visual studio 2010...

*Thanks!
  Stefan*

Comment: It seems that the "Client Profile" is not so client-ish, given the size of 250 megs. Why bother with the client profile when the whole 3.5 framework has the same size?

Comment: You are right. For .net 3.5 the client profile is not a big advantage (maybe it's not an advantage at all).

For .net 4 it is a real advantage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the name mismatch, "Setup" is missing from the one you downloaded.  Rename the file so its name matches the name VS is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you download manually the file, offline setup will work. But if later you change the option back to `Download prerequisites from Vendor's site` the setup will download the online installer and it will try to compare its hash with the one belonging to the file you copied manually and the user will get an

> Setup has detected that the file DontNetFx35ClientSetup.exe has either
>   changed since it was initially published or may be corrupt

If you want the online installer to work again, you need to put again the `280kb DotNetFx35ClientSetup.exe` back in the Bootstrapper packages folder.